# loop through nested json object without knowing the object names

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to loop through a nested json object and replace values when the key matches.. but have a mental blank when it comes to the nested values. Any help would be appreciated
My Json file will look something like this:

```
{
 "Type":{
    "car": "Ford"
 },
"message": [
     { "reference_code": "XD383839",
       "reference_number": "8837XC",
       "color" : "Blue"
     }
     ]
} 

json_object.load(json_file.json)

for key, value in json_object.items()
    for nested in value:
       if nested = "my search item"
           #replace the value of the nested item and replace it
           print(nested) #This only gives me the object and not the value
```

I'm sure this is a simple issue.

Comment: what is `value`?  You say "only gives me the object"...what type of object?  Your question is unanswerable if you don't explain what your initial data structure looks like.  Can you include a line at the top of your code that sets `json_object` to some hard-coded value that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: the json will look something like this:

{"car": "Ford",
"message": {
    "reference_code": "XD383839",
    reference_number": "8837XC"
} }

I need the value of reference_number

Comment: Please update your question to include that data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you wanted:

import json

```
json_object = json.loads('{"car": "Ford", "message": { "reference_code": "XD383839", "reference_number": "8837XC" } }')

for key, value in json_object.items():
    for nested in value:
       if nested == 'reference_number':
           print(value[nested])
```

Result:

```
8837XC
```

The key idea is that `for nested in value:` will iterate over the keys in a dict, as you suggest.  So once you have the key identified, then you need to go back to the original dict you're iterating over, `value`, and get the value for that specific key.

Your code is doing something a little bit strange, and you may not have intended for it to do that.  When it iterates over the value for the key `car`, it is iterating over a string, because the value associated with that key is a string.  So it's testing to see if each of the letters in the string `"Ford"` match the key name that you're looking for.  I assume that's not what you really want to do.

Here's how I would fix this issue:

```
for key, value in json_object.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for nested in value:
            if nested == 'reference_number':
               print(value[nested])
```

Once you've qualified the inner loop like this so that you know you're only working on `dict` objects, you can then do the same thing that you did for the outer loop:

```
for key, value in json_object.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for nested_key, nested_value in value.items():
            if nested_key == 'reference_number':
               print(nested_value)
```

Or, why do the inner iteration at all:

```
for key, value in json_object.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict) and 'reference_number' in value:
        print(value['reference_number'])
```